# Does CodeIgniter's ci_sessions need occasional emptying?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using CI's sessions in connection with a  database. So all of our sessions are in this ci_sessions table on our database and it can get a lot of rows, considering that the session_id keep changing every 5 minutes.

Do we need to empty the table, say every one a month / week maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, CodeIgniter cleans up after itself...

**Note**
According to the [CodeIgniter documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html):

*The Session class has built-in garbage collection which clears out expired sessions so you do not need to write your own routine to do it.*

CodeIgniter's Session Class probably checks the session table and cleans up expired entries.  However, the documentation does not say when the clean up happens.  Since there are no cron jobs as part of CodeIgniter, the clean up must occur when the Session class is invoked.  I suppose if the site remains idle forever, the session table will never be cleared.  But, this would be an unusual case.

Comment: See added Note above.  If you have a long expiration date, the table make take a long time to clear.

Comment: can u please tell me if which system file is used to delete row from ci_session table?

Comment: @NikoliusLau see my answer for the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39986478/1873197

Answer (score 13):

While what @Marc-Audet said is true, if you take a look at the code, you can see it is a really lousy way to clean up sessions.

The constructor calls the `_sess_gc` function every time it is initiated. So, basically each request to your server if you have it autoloaded.

Then, it generates a random number below 100 and sees if that's below a certain value (by default it is 5). If this condition is met, then it will remove any rows on the session table with `last_activity` value less than current time minus your session expiration.

While this works for most cases, it is technically possible that (if the world is truly random) the random number generator does not generate a number below 5 for a long time, in which case, your sessions will not be cleaned up.

Also, if you have your session expiry time set to a long time (if you set to 0, CI will set it to 2 years) then those rows are not going to get deleted anyway. And if your site is good enough to get a decent amount of visitors, your DBA will be pointing fingers at the session table some time soon :)

It works for most cases - but I would not call it a proper solution. Their session id regeneration really should have been built to remove the records pertaining to the previous ids and the garbage collection really should not be left to a random number - in theory, it is possible that the required number is not generated as frequently as you wished.

In our case, I have removed the session garbage collection from the session library and I manually take care of it once a day (with a cron job .. and a reasonable session expiration time). This reduces the number of unnecessary hits to the DB and also does not leave a massive table in the DB. It is still a big table, but lot smaller than what it used to be.

Comment: Your insightful comments are instructional and helpful, thank you.  The cron job technique is very useful.  I used a similar method to clean up a directory of temporary PDF files generated as part of a reporting system.

Comment: well thanks for this important information about CI session, very appreciate it @dakdad :)

Answer (score 9):

Given the fact that the OP question doesn't have a CodeIgniter 2 tag, I'll answer how to deal with sessions cleanup when the database keeps growing for CodeIgniter 3.

**Issue:**
When you set (in the config.php file) `sess_expiration` key too high (let's say 1 year) and `sess_time_to_update` key low (let's say 5 min), the session table will keep growing as the users browse though your website, until sessions rows will expire and will be garbage collected (which is 1 year).

**Solution:**
Setting `sess_regenerate_destroy` key to `TRUE` (default set to `FALSE`) will delete an old session when it  will regenerate itself with the new id, thus cleaning your table automatically.

Answer (score 4):

CodeIgniter implements the [SessionHandlerInterface](http://php.net/sessionhandlerinterface) (see the docs for the [custom driver](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#custom-drivers)).

CodeIgniter defines a garbage collector method named **gc()** for each driver (database, file, redis, etc) or you can define your custom gc() for your custom driver.

The **gc()** method is passed to PHP with the [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) function, therefore **the garbage collector is called internally by PHP** based on [session.gc_divisor](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor), [session.gc_probability](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) settings.

For example, with the following settings:

```
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 100
```

There is a 1% chance that the garbage collector process starts on each request.

So, you do not need to clean the session table if your settings are properly set.

Answer (score 1):

When you call:

`$this->session->sess_destroy();`

It deletes the information in database by itself.

Comment: well, i never use sess_destroy on my site.. so i have to delete it manually then?

Comment: `sess_destroy` only deletes the records pertaining to the current session_id of the user. The rest of the records will only get cleaned up by `_sess_gc`

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP7, the GC-based method is *disabled* by default, as per the documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-gc.php Stumbled upon this because a legacy application suddenly stopped working, reaching a system limitation since sessions are never ever cleaned up. A cronjob to clean up the sessions would be a good idea...

Answer (score -2):

It is always good practice to clear the table. Otherwise, if your querying the session data for say creating reports or something, it will be slow and unreliable. Nevertheless, given the performance of mysql, yes do so.